# Runge-Kutta methods with discontinuity

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

Would Runge_Kutta methods (especially Dormand-Prince) pair be affected by step-like nature of the derivative function $\dot{y} = f(t,y)$.

I mean if we take it $\dot{y}=f(u(t),y)$ and $u(t)$ is step-wise inputs (discrete + Zero order hold).

Thanks

Comment: What is discrete plus zero order hold? Your ability to do local and global error estimation is compromised when you lose smoothness, is that what you are interested in?

Comment: By discrete + zero order hold I mean u is constant between two sampling time points. And its value changes after each sampling time.

Comment: This is a highly unusual situation. If the driving function changes dramatically during a single time step, then time step is probably too large. What sort of effects are you interested in?

Comment: It is a general, commonly known computer control, when you have a discrete (digital) controller and continuous plant model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the question text from your [other question at SO on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60109459) <sub>(that you deleted as suggested, but did not transfer to enhance this question)</sub>.

> **Q:** I want to simulate continuous system with zero order hold inputs (piece-wise constant). Actually we can change $f$, as it is a function of time, according to some external input.

**A:** In $$y'(t)=f(t,y(t),u(t)),$$ each constant segment $u(t)=u_k$ on $t\in[t_k,t_{k+1})$ can be considered to generate an independent ODE system 
$$y'(t)=f_k(t,y(t))~\text{ where }~f_k(t,y)=f(t,y,u_k).$$ 
Each of these systems on their own is smooth, thus perfectly solvable with reasonable step sizes, as long as it does not diverge to infinity.

Then you can construct a composite function that is the solution of the original equation, 
$$y(t)=y_k(t) ~\text{ for }~ t\in[t_k,t_{k+1}]$$
where $y_k$ is a solution to
$$
y_k'(t)=f_k(t,y_k(t)),~~y_k(t_k)=y_{k-1}(t_k).
$$

> **Q:** However, the problem that arises in this case is the integrator uses some adaptive step size and when you ask it to find output until some time $t$ it may also make use of some future values of the $f(t,y)$ which would be wrong, because after that time our input and hence the $f(t,y)$ changes.

**A:** That is not really a problem if you compute the solutions separately. On the segment $[t_k,t_{k+1}]$, the solution is equal to the solution of the $k$th equation. That the solver uses points outside this interval does not change its exactness inside the interval, to the contrary, it allows the solver to keep using relatively large step sizes.

Changing the equation exactly at $t_{k+1}$ would introduce a discontinuity in the equation or one of its derivatives which throws off the step size controller, leading to excessively small step sizes and the corresponding large number of function evaluations to pass over that point.

Comment: Your last paragraph does not contradict the previous paragraph, right? If we do simulation separately, then there is no problem, right?

Comment: Also, do you think that it is not a good way of simulating the output of a continuous system with digital controller inputs (step-wise)?

Comment: The computation to reach $t_{k+1}$ may use simulated values of $y'=f_k$ for $t>t_{k+1}$, but that has no or minimal influence on the values inside the interval $[t_k,t_{k+1}]$ that are relevant to the controller. It is a question of design choice in the solver algorithm if the last step ends directly at the upper interval bound, or if the value there is interpolated from a larger step. It is not easy to detect this difference without tracing the calls to the right-side function.

Comment: Some ODE solver packages have extensive event support, where you can define event actions and also force a list of stop times to be nodes of the internal time sequence. With that the discussion of over-shooting would be unnecessary. If you want to stay with scipy, then use the stepper class `RK45` to implement such a stop-times list, as the `solve_ivp` interface is rather deficient in that regard.